# long <-> str binary conversion

Tags: python, string, bignum

Is there any lib that convert very long numbers to string just copying the data?

These one-liners are too slow:

```
def xlong(s):
    return sum([ord(c) << e*8 for e,c in enumerate(s)])

def xstr(x):
    return chr(x&255) + xstr(x >> 8) if x else ''

print xlong('abcd'*1024) % 666
print xstr(13**666)
```

Answer (score 4):

You want the struct module.

```
packed = struct.pack('l', 123456)
assert struct.unpack('l', packed)[0] == 123456
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify

def xstr(x):
    hex = '%x' % x
    return unhexlify('0'*(len(hex)%2) + hex)[::-1]

def xlong(s):
    return int(hexlify(s[::-1]), 16)
```

I didn't time it but it should be faster and also work on larger numbers, since it doesn't use recursion.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, I have a lack of long(s,256) . I lurk more and see that there are 2 function in Python CAPI file "longobject.h":

```
PyObject * _PyLong_FromByteArray( const unsigned char* bytes, size_t n, int little_endian, int is_signed);
int _PyLong_AsByteArray(PyLongObject* v, unsigned char* bytes, size_t n, int little_endian, int is_signed);
```

They do the job. I don't know why there are not included in some python module, or correct me if I'am wrong.

Comment: In Python3 there are `int.from_bytes`/`int.to_bytes` methods. http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=int.from_bytes#int.to_bytes

Answer (score 1):

If you need fast serialization use [marshal](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-marshal.html) module. It's around 400x faster than your methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't care about the string format, you just want a serialization?  If so, why not use Python's built-in serializer, the [cPickle](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-cPickle.html) module?  The `dumps` function will convert any python object including a long integer to a string, and the `loads` function is its inverse.  If you're doing this for saving out to a file, check out the `dump` and `load` functions, too.

```
>>> import cPickle
>>> print cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps(13**666)) % 666
73
>>> print (13**666) % 666
73
```

Answer (score -1):

Performance of `cPickle` vs. `marshal` (Python 2.5.2, Windows):

```
python -mtimeit -s"from cPickle import loads,dumps;d=13**666" "loads(dumps(d))"
1000 loops, best of 3: 600 usec per loop

python -mtimeit -s"from marshal import loads,dumps;d=13**666" "loads(dumps(d))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.79 usec per loop

python -mtimeit -s"from pickle import loads,dumps;d= 13**666" "loads(dumps(d))"
1000 loops, best of 3: 644 usec per loop
```

`marshal` is much faster.

Comment: Only if you use it naively. pickle defaults to a textual backward-compatible protocol.  Use cPickle.dumps(d,-1) and the times become competitive: on my machine, 4.63 usec/loop for cPickle vs 3.34 usec/loop for marshal.