# Why is `pickle.dump`+`pickle.load` IPC so slow and are there fast alternatives?

Tags: performance, io, ipc, python-2.x

I am doing IPC with a python subprocess. For now, let's assume I have to use `subprocess.Popen` to spawn the other process, so I can't use `multiprocessing.Pipe` for communication. The first thing, that came to my mind is to use their STDIO streams with `pickle.load`+`pickle.dump` (don't worry about security right now).

However, I noticed, that the transfer rates are just *terrible*: order of 750KB/s on my machine! This is slower than communicating via `multiprocessing.Pipe` by a factor of 95, which uses `pickle` as well, as far as I understand it. There is no benefit in using `cPickle` either.

(**Update**: Note, I realized, this is only the case on python2! On python3 it works fine.)

Why is this so terribly slow? I suspect the reason is somewhere in the way that IO is performed in `.dump`/`.load` via python file objects not the C file descriptors. Maybe it has something to do with the GIL?

Is there any way cross-platform way to get the same speed as `multiprocessing.Pipe`?

I have already found out, that on linux it is possible to use `_multiprocessing.Connection` (or `multiprocessing.connection.Connection` on python3) to wrap the STDIO file descriptors of the subprocess and get what I want. However, this is not possible on win32, and I don't even know about Mac.

Benchmark:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from timeit import default_timer
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import pickle
import sys
import os
import numpy
try:
    from _multiprocessing import Connection as _Connection
except ImportError:
    from multiprocessing.connection import Connection as _Connection

def main(args):
    if args:
        worker(connect(args[0], sys.stdin, sys.stdout))
    else:
        benchmark()

def worker(conn):
    while True:
        try:
            amount = conn.recv()
        except EOFError:
            break
        else:
            conn.send(numpy.random.random(amount))
    conn.close()

def benchmark():
    for amount in numpy.arange(11)*10000:
        pickle = parent('pickle', amount, 1)
        pipe = parent('pipe', amount, 1)
        print(pickle[0]/1000, pickle[1], pipe[1])

def parent(channel, amount, repeat):
    start = default_timer()
    proc = Popen([sys.executable, '-u', __file__, channel],
                stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    conn = connect(channel, proc.stdout, proc.stdin)
    for i in range(repeat):
        conn.send(amount)
        data = conn.recv()
    conn.close()
    end = default_timer()
    return data.nbytes, end - start

class PickleConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, recv, send):
        self._recv = recv
        self._send = send
    def recv(self):
        return pickle.load(self._recv)
    def send(self, data):
        pickle.dump(data, self._send)
    def close(self):
        self._recv.close()
        self._send.close()

class PipeConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, recv_fd, send_fd):
        self._recv = _Connection(recv_fd)
        self._send = _Connection(send_fd)
    def recv(self):
        return self._recv.recv()
    def send(self, data):
        self._send.send(data)
    def close(self):
        self._recv.close()
        self._send.close()

def connect(channel, recv, send):
    recv_fd = os.dup(recv.fileno())
    send_fd = os.dup(send.fileno())
    recv.close()
    send.close()
    if channel == 'pipe':
        return PipeConnection(recv_fd, send_fd)
    elif channel == 'pickle':
        return PickleConnection(os.fdopen(recv_fd, 'rb', 0),
                                os.fdopen(send_fd, 'wb', 0))
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid channel: %s" % channel)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Results:

[image: benchmark]

Many thanks for reading,

Thomas

**Update:**

Okay, so I profiled this as suggested by @martineau. The following results are obtained in independent invocations for a single run with the fixed value of `amount=500000`.

In the parent process, the top calls sorted by *tottime* are:

```
      11916 function calls (11825 primitive calls) in 5.382 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    35    4.471    0.128    4.471    0.128 {method 'readline' of 'file' objects}
    52    0.693    0.013    0.693    0.013 {method 'read' of 'file' objects}
     4    0.062    0.016    0.063    0.016 {method 'decode' of 'str' objects}
```

In the subprocess:

```
      11978 function calls (11855 primitive calls) in 5.298 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    52    4.476    0.086    4.476    0.086 {method 'write' of 'file' objects}
    73    0.552    0.008    0.552    0.008 {repr}
     3    0.112    0.037    0.112    0.037 {method 'read' of 'file' objects}
```

This got me worried, that the usage `readline` may be the reason for the bad performance.

The following connection uses only `pickle.dumps`/`pickle.loads` together with `write`/`read`.

```
class DumpsConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, recv, send):
        self._recv = recv
        self._send = send
    def recv(self):
        raw_len = self._recvl(4)
        content_len = struct.unpack('>I', raw_len)[0]
        content = self._recvl(content_len)
        return pickle.loads(content)
    def send(self, data):
        content = pickle.dumps(data)
        self._send.write(struct.pack('>I', len(content)))
        self._send.write(content)
    def _recvl(self, size):
        data = b''
        while len(data) < size:
            packet = self._recv.read(size - len(data))
            if not packet:
                raise EOFError
            data += packet
        return data
    def close(self):
        self._recv.close()
        self._send.close()
```

Indeed, its speed is only 14 times worse than that of `multiprocessing.Pipe`. (Which is still terrible)

Profiling now, in parent:

```
      11935 function calls (11844 primitive calls) in 1.749 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     2    1.385    0.692    1.385    0.692 {method 'read' of 'file' objects}
     4    0.125    0.031    0.125    0.031 {method 'decode' of 'str' objects}
     4    0.056    0.014    0.228    0.057 pickle.py:961(load_string)
```

in child:

```
      11996 function calls (11873 primitive calls) in 1.627 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    73    1.099    0.015    1.099    0.015 {repr}
     3    0.231    0.077    0.231    0.077 {method 'read' of 'file' objects}
     2    0.055    0.028    0.055    0.028 {method 'write' of 'file' objects}
```

So, I still have no real clue, what to use instead.

Comment: Since you're using `multiprocessing` the GIL shouldn't be the issue. I suggest you use the [`profile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#) module to analyze where the code is spending the majority of its time.

Comment: There's good information on [profiling Python Code](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Profiling_Code) on the [PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips - Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips).

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the suggestions and the nice link! I had already tried `cProfile` briefly in my actual application and got the info that most of tottime was spent in "{method 'read' of 'file' objects}" (6.1s) and "{method 'readline' of 'file' objects}" (2.9s).  I am now too tired, but tomorrow I will try this for the basic example provided here. BTW: I am NOT using `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Yes, I see now you're not actually using `multiprocessing.Process`, just `multiprocessing.Connection`. However what you do with `Popen` and `sys.executable` is equivalent with regards to not having any GIL issues, I would think.

Comment: “...what to use instead.” - maybe https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-python ? It seams to be fastest http://jmoiron.net/blog/python-serialization/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/329127/650222) suggests to use:

```
pickle.dump(data, file, -1)
```

i.e. setting the protocol to the newest version available. Indeed, this increases the speed to be only worse than `multiprocessing.Pipe` by a factor of about 1.7 on my machine. Using `cPickle` improves this to a factor of about 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problem with pickle/cPickle serializing the numpy array:

```
In [14]: timeit cPickle.dumps(numpy.random.random(1000))
1000 loops, best of 3: 727 us per loop

In [15]: timeit numpy.random.random(1000).dumps()
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.6 us per loop
```

The problem only occurs with serializing, deserializing are fine:

```
In [16]: timeit cPickle.loads(numpy.random.random(1000).dumps())
10000 loops, best of 3: 40 us per loop
```

You could use marshal module,  witch is even faster (but not safe):

```
In [19]: timeit marshal.loads(marshal.dumps(numpy.random.random(1000)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.8 us per loop
```

Well I recommended msgpack, but it do not have support for numpy, and one lib that have it is terrible slow, anyway python-msgpack do not have support for buffers nor has zerocopy feature so its not possible to do efficient support for numpy.

Comment: Great hints! I suppose, I will probably use a combination of `marshal.dump`+`marshal.load` with `numpy.<type>.dumps`+`numpy.loads`. I guess this is easier than msgpack if using this on windows well. I don't think though, that the bad performance is due to pickle serialization problems (benchmark suggest something goes wrong with IO?)